# How to use LevelDB in go?

Tags: go, leveldb

From http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/, it seems not explicit or easy to use LevelDB with Go.
But I really want to know how to use it in Go.

Could anyone give me a clue?

Comment: You are right. I do believe that you can get it by google conveniently. But actually Google doesn't work very well in my area. Believing it or not, I do have tried it in our common search engine and got nothing. http://www.baidu.com/s?bs=golang&f=8&rsv_bp=1&rsv_spt=3&wd=leveldb+golang&inputT=4966

Comment: If you have access http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/ to then this should work for you too: http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=golang+leveldb&projectsearch=Search+projects

Comment: Yes, it works sometimes. And I have been impossible to access to golang.org for more than 10 hours. Can you imagine that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [leveldb-go](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb-go/), ported by the Go Authors.

Comment: as for 2012/07/06 looks like it is a rewrite from scratch which is not there yet. See leveldb.go: func (d *DB) Get()...{ panic("unimplemented") }

Comment: The leveldb port to Golang still isn't complete.

Comment: Bad news. Even 6 years in the future, it's still not done.

Comment: Bad news 2.0. Still not done after 10 years.

Comment: Bad news 3.0. The whole thing has been canceled now.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a Go implementation of LevelDB https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb

Here is how to use it:

```
go get github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb
```

Create or open database:

```
db, err := leveldb.OpenFile("path/to/db", nil)
...
defer db.Close()
...
```

Read or modify the database content:

```
data, err := db.Get([]byte("key"), nil)
...
err = db.Put([]byte("key"), []byte("value"), nil)
...
err = db.Delete([]byte("key"), nil)
...
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [levigo](https://github.com/jmhodges/levigo) - a Golang wrapper around the C++ version of [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/).

The file [levigo/leveldb_test.go](http://github.com/jmhodges/levigo/blob/master/leveldb_test.go) gives you an example of how to use levigo.